# how many custom attributes type in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, category, attributes, catalog, sql

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'image1', array(
'input'         => 'image',
'type'          => 'varchar',
'group' => 'Slider Image',
'label'         => 'Image 1',
'visible'       => 1,
'required'      => 0,
'user_defined' => 1,
'backend'  => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
'frontend_input' =>'',
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'visible_on_front'  => 1,
));
```

how many input type for custom attribute like text,textarea

```
'input' => 'text',
```

can we add **button** as custom attribute and set action on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issue in your installer please try below

```
$installer->addAttribute("catalog_category", "image1",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "catalog/category_attribute_backend_image",
    "frontend" => "",
    "label"    => "Image one",
    "input"    => "image",
    "class"    => "",
    "source"   => "",
    "global"   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "user_defined"  => false,
    "default" => "Image",
    "searchable" => false,
    "filterable" => false,
    "comparable" => false,
    'group' => 'Slider Image',

    "visible_on_front"  => true,
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));
```

Comment: are ku6 problem nae he